# Can a bash script that launches vim abort being in a pipeline?

Tags: bash, vim

I have a bash script that launches vim for me, after it reads some input from the command line.

I use it to edit scripts I have somewhere in the path, easily. It does some other things too, but the simplest form of it is the following:

#### vibin.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PROG=$(which "$1")
vim "$PROG"
```

Often I'll be using this to edit something I recently ran, to make a quick adjustement.
For example, if I ran

```
$ my_script.sh a b c d
```

I might go back in the history, then insert `vibin.sh` at the start of the line to edit it.

```
$ vibin.sh myscript.sh a b c d
```

This works fine, but fails if my previous command was being piped to something, e.g.

```
$ vibin.sh myscript.sh a b c d | tee /tmp/out
```

Is there a way to make my script abort being in a pipeline, and allow this to work correctly? Currently vim gets into a weird state when I do this, which I can exit, but I'd prefer a better solution

Currently I can detect if I'm running in a pipeline, and abort, but i'd like to actually have it do what I wanted - edit the script!

```
# ensure we're not in a pipeline
if [ ! -t 1 ] ; then 
  exit 1;
fi
```

Comment: Try `vim "$PROG" < /dev/tty > /dev/tty`

Comment: that worked - can you add that as an answer? thanks @phd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
vim "$PROG" < /dev/tty > /dev/tty
```

That is, force redirect standard input/output from/to the current console. A workaround against pipe/redirects.